# Drawing Flow Charts in Delphi

Tags: delphi, delphi-7

what should i look for to start writing a software to design flow charts in delphi?
is there any example out there? any library or code sample?

thanks;

Answer (score 3):

TMS has some nice chart components:
http://www.tmssoftware.com/site/advchart.asp

Answer (score 1):

I know [DevExpress has a flowchart library.](http://www.devexpress.com/products/vcl/ExFlowChart/)  I've used it and it works pretty well.  It's not free, though.

Comment: is there any other choise?, i would like to have my owen to improve and stuff

Answer (score 1):

I asked about [drawing and sizing shapes at run time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2228661/draw-and-manipulate-shapes-at-run-time) a while ago.  Some of the answers might be useful for you.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the source code for [StarUML](http://sourceforge.net/projects/staruml/files/). Its a complete working implimentation of a diagramming tool and it integrates directly into the IDE. Granted, it's UML diagrams, not flowcharts but you should be able to glean a lot of ideas from it. The project has since transitioned to Java but still has the original Delphi code as a downloadable zip file.

If you intend to create a commercial product keep in mind that it is licensed under the GPL.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what your time constraints are, its really *not that difficult* to create this yourself using the drawing methods in TCanvas. (or for the more adventurous, using GDI/GDI+/Direct2D directly).

The benefit of doing this is that you are not then dependent on the 3rd party component,  can make it do exactly what you want, and not have to make your app fit the component's way of thinking.  Plus, there's no licensing issuses, since you wrote it.

The downside, of course, is that you need to to it all yourself.

The key to a drawing app like a flow charter is actually storing the data.  Each shape should be an instance of an object that has several methods such as draw().  Different shapes should have diffeerent decendent classes, each with their own overloaded draw() method to draw that shape.  Shapes can be stored in a TList or similar container.  To draw the document, iterate the list of objects and call its draw method.

Comment: that what i was asking, do u have any idea what i should be reading? any sample or anything to get me in the right direction?

Comment: also wich one should i use to that will be anti analising? so i dont waste time re-writing; thanks

Comment: There was & may still be a simple drawing example I believe that came with Delphi that showed how to draw shapes in response to mouse actions. I dont know if its still there as I dont have them installed.  I dont know of any other intro to basic delphi graphics though I'm sure if you look online you'd find tons.  Basically, what you want to learn how to use is TCanvas and its methods.  Each paint box/timage has its own canvas object - you just set the brush and line colors, and tell it to draw rectangles, polygons, etc. Typically you do that in the OnPaint event.

Comment: To handle drawing things out, react to the mousemove & up/down events which pass coordinates.  For antialiasing, GDI+ (you'd need a 3rd party interface to that) and Direct2D (if your version of Delphi supports it) can do that.  BUT, I really recommend starting with the basic TCanvas drawing routines first as you dont want to make things more complicated than you need at first.

Comment: If you start working with graphics and have more specific questions about how to handle certain tasks, just post more questions.  There's plenty of Delphi experts here.